# Clear Cache and Cookies on Flutter Web

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

Currently I am working on a project which has a login with oAuth2 from the webview. But the problem is I need to clear the cookies so that i can login again via the webview. As if now it auto logins itself and redirects but i want to make the user login every time.
And this is for flutter web part, currently i am using this plugin

```
webviewx 0.2.1
https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx
```

Which has a support for web as well but no mechanism to clear the cookies

Previously i was using the plugin that supports only mobile

```
webview_flutter: ^2.3.1
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
```

Any one has any idea how i can implement it and also clear the cookies and the cache and it supports mobile and web platform as well.

Comment: tried `clearCache` method?

Comment: Did try it but it seems it does not work it redirects even if i clear the cache on weviewCreated. Cannot see the login page

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://yoursite.org/register',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                webViewController.clearCache();
              },
            );
```